# Converting the result of Func<T, IConvertible> to int in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, generics, casting, functional-programming

I am abstracting a bit of code, and ran into an issue with casting the result of a Func to an integer for comparison.

I have a function:

```
public static IConvertible GetIllnessRateByParity(IEnumerable<ILLNESS_OBJECT> pItems, int pParity, Func<ILLNESS_OBJECT, IConvertible> pSelector)
    {
        var filtered = pItems.Where(a => a.Parity == pParity);
        return Math.Round(filtered.Count(a => Convert.ToInt32(pSelector(a)) == 1) / (double)GetBirthCountByParity(pItems, pParity), 2);
    }

public class ILLNESS_OBJECT
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public int Parity { get; set; }
    public int Afterbirth { get; set; }
    public int OvaryInfection { get; set; }
    etc...
}
```

Which calculates the rate of a specific illness within a set of data. The illness to be analysed is input through a selector, which selects an IConvertible value from the ILLNESS_OBJECT object.

I call the method like this:

```
GetIllnessRateByParity(data, 1, a => a.AfterBirth)
```

data is an IEnumerable with non-null values.

The method throws an InvalidCastException at the Convert.ToInt32(pSelector(a)) part without clear indication of why this cast fails, could anyone explain it to me? I am under the impression that pSelector(a) returns an IConvertible value which is cast-compatible with int, right? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Exception message:
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in CONFIDENTIAL.CLASS.dll but was not handled in user code

Message: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: The exception doesn't have any extra information in it? eg what is the message that goes with the exception?

Comment: Have you checked the specific implementation of IConvertible that your pSelector returns? Is it maybe the implementation that just doesn't support ToInt32 / throws the exception there?

Comment: "I am under the impression that pSelector(a) returns an IConvertible value which is cast-compatible with int" - I don't think this is the case but I also don't think it is important. What is happening is that it is calling the following overload of `ToInt32`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys(v=vs.110).aspx and then doing what Jeroen says.

Comment: Why don't just change `Func<ILLNESS_OBJECT, IConvertible> pSelector` to `Func<ILLNESS_OBJECT, int> pSelector`?

Comment: There's no overload of Convert.ToInt32 that takes an IConvertable, that's why the runtime will fallback to calling the overload @Chris noted. Also you tagged the question with functional-programming, but you're using interfaces which are more OOP than functional, Roman's idea is more functional. And your class has mutable fields.

Comment: @RomanKoliada: I assume that sometimes it might return something that isn't an int (eg a double, a long, a byte or something else).

Comment: but you always can convert you value to int in the Func. See my anwer

Comment: @RomanKoliada: Ah, I see what you mean. It does still rely on the OP being able to change the signature but if he can then yeah, shifting the responsibility does make everything a bit simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately due to the requirements of the code I prefer to use an interface over multiple overloads of the method signature, I indeed need floats, doubles, and decimals

Comment: Can't you do that with a generic method signature, instead of multiple overloads?

Comment: I've checked your code. [For me it is working.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WDXm9G)

Comment: @IvanR. Nice to see it working! Do you have any guess as to why I'm getting InvalidCastExceptions?

Comment: Maybe environment issue. Which version .NET do you use?

Comment: I use version 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter is called pSelector, but it's not actually a selector.

It's just returning a value (int, float...), and the actual selection is being done by the labmda in the Count method:

```
filtered.Count(a => Convert.ToInt32(pSelector(a)) == 1)
```

So pSelector is going to return a value of some data type, and then you're relying on being able to convert that to an int32.

But you only need to do that to compare it to 1. Given the info in your question, you don't really need an int32, you need a bool.

So what if you refactor pSelector to be a selector, by moving the comparison to 1 inside the selector:

```
public static double GetIllnessRateByParity(IEnumerable<ILLNESS_OBJECT> pItems, int pParity, Func<ILLNESS_OBJECT, bool> pSelector)
{
    var filtered = pItems.Where(a => a.Parity == pParity);
    return Math.Round(filtered.Count(pSelector) / (double)GetBirthCountByParity(pItems, pParity), 2);
}
GetIllnessRateByParity(data, 1, a => a.AfterBirth==1)
```

Comment: I consider the comparison to be an implementation detail so I moved it into the method, I agree with your feedback on my naming scheme though, thanks!

Comment: After consideration I'm going to accept your answer, this way doesn't require difficult conversions, and gives the method more flexibility over the selector

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TWXJdY)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new List<ILLNESS_OBJECT>{
                new ILLNESS_OBJECT{ ID = 1, Parity = 1, Day = DateTime.Now, SomeString = "1", Long = 2L},
                new ILLNESS_OBJECT{ ID = 2, Parity = 2, Day = DateTime.Now, SomeString = "1", Long = 2L},
                new ILLNESS_OBJECT{ ID = 3, Parity = 1, Day = DateTime.Now, SomeString = "2", Long = 1L},
                new ILLNESS_OBJECT{ ID = 4, Parity = 1, Day = DateTime.Now, SomeString = "3", Long = 3L},
        };
        Console.WriteLine(GetIllnessRateByParity(data, 1, x => x.ID));
        Console.WriteLine(GetIllnessRateByParity(data, 1, x => int.Parse(x.SomeString)));
        Console.WriteLine(GetIllnessRateByParity(data, 1, x => (DateTime.Now - x.Day).Days + 1));
        Console.WriteLine(GetIllnessRateByParity(data, 1, x => (int)x.Long));
    }

    public static IConvertible GetIllnessRateByParity(IEnumerable<ILLNESS_OBJECT> pItems, int pParity, Func<ILLNESS_OBJECT, int> pSelector)
    {
        var filtered = pItems.Where(a => a.Parity == pParity);
        return Math.Round(filtered.Count(a => pSelector(a) == 1)/(double)1, 2);
    }

}

public class ILLNESS_OBJECT
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public int Parity { get; set; }
    public int Afterbirth { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public long Long { get; set; }
}
```